# Why the spatial reference of a GeoTIFF image (generated in Python) is missing in ArcGIS?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I have a NC file that I am converting it to a GeoTIFF in Python. Here is the code I am using:

```
lat_bounds, lon_bounds = [-8, 5], [40, 65]

lat_indices = np.where((lat > lat_bounds[0]) & (lat < lat_bounds[1]))[0]
lon_indices = np.where((lon > lon_bounds[0]) & (lon < lon_bounds[1]))[1]

subset = co_data[lat_indices.min():lat_indices.max(), lon_indices.min():lon_indices.max()]

xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [-8,40,5,65]
nrows,ncols = np.shape(subset)
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)   

output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(r"C:\Users\....\test1.tif",ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  
srs = osr.SpatialReference()                 
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                     
                                             
output_raster.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )   
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(subset)   
output_raster.FlushCache()
```

However when opening my file in ArcGIS or QGIS I get an error message that the image's spatial reference is missing.

Comment: What exactly was created by your code? Are there sidecar files? What does gdalinfo say about the georeference?

Comment: If you print srs.ExportToWkt(), does it look correct?

Comment: @bugmenot123 My code is generating a GeoTiff file. No  sidecar files. How Can I check gdalinfo?

Comment: @user30184 I printed srs.ExportToWkt() but still the same error

Comment: But did it look correct? Was is a string that seemed to define EPSG:4326 right? Is should be like `GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]`.

Comment: Do you mean the out put geotiff look correct? The value look ok but the coordinate no of course as it's not referenced. I used srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326) to specify WGS84 lat long.

Comment: Does it work if you add `output_raster.Close()` at the end?

Comment: No it doesn't. In fact when I am including output_raster.Close(), it's returning another error: AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'